# How save setting after next run

Tags: office-addins, office365-apps

How do I save settings in a Word add-in so that they're available after next run? I'm creating a task pane add-in with two settings and want to load them automatically every time the add-in runs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to follow what is stated in [Persisting add-in state and settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123509.aspx) TechNet Library. Basically it is allowed to use local add-on storage or in some cases call local web storage or cookie.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to save settings an your office 365 app in JavaScript:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set('settings1','100');
```

This is how to retrieve settings in your o365 app in JavaScript:

```
write('Current value for mySetting: ' + Office.context.document.settings.get('settings1'));

// Function that writes to a div with id='message' on the page.
function write(message){
    document.getElementById('message').innerText += message; 
}
```

Hope this helps.